# My DAL won't work with an ASP.NET MVC web app because of what in it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC web app and copied off my DAL from my 3 layer app as the lesson video says it and when I was about to test it, I get an error saying that I can't [do it of "new"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF6eD.png) [and here the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFtrS.png)

I tried removing it and it doesn't work, I tried to copy a sample of DAL from the sample copy of ASP.NET MVC web app but its didn't work as well, so whatever I tried it doesn't work.

Comment: Did the lesson video indeed instruct you to create an old .NET 4 project to copy the code to?

Comment: It's a bad lesson...

Comment: you can to use "new" for newer version  c#,
for oldest  version c# you must use " new nameclass()" 
for your example is new sqlconnection ()